# Index not creating from couchdb with logstash Logstash

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, couchdb, logstash

I am using this config file to create index/import data from couchdb.

```
input { 
   couchdb_changes {
    db => "roles"
    host => "localhost"
    port => 5984
}
}
output {
elasticsearch { 
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
    host => "localhost"
    index => "roles_index"
    protocol => "http"
    host => localhost
    port => 9200
  }
}
```

I was able to run logstash with this config file and import data 
once. I closed command prompt to shutdown logstash and reran cmd prompt 
and stash with the config file again. but now I cannot see any index 
created. Is there anything that I might be doing wrong here. I am using 
ctl+c to kill logstash in cmd prompt. Will appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: sometimes it happens so with elasticsearch npm in node.js that it does not work when you define `host=> localhost` I experienced it.  So what I did was to define it like this `host:'127.0.0.1:9200'` when creating the client. Try and let me know if this is answers you. Happy Coding

Comment: that didn't help unfortunately .

Comment: Anything in your elasticsearch logs? How about running logstash with --debug?

Answer (score 0):

in case someone comes here looking for the answer of same thing...I set sequence_path => "my_couchdb_seq" in couchdb_changes { } section of my config file and it worked. Each time i want to run logstash to create index, value in this file should be replaced with 0. Got to link: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/index-not-creating-from-couchdb-with-logstash/27848/9 for details